# .3DS to OpenGL-ES 2.0

Tags: json, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I would ask you what are OpenGL ES limits.This is my situation: I have to create a .3DS to .JSON converter (*.JSON must be readable from OpenGL ES libraries after conversion*).

Example: OpenGL ES can't manage more than x lights,texture can't be more than xy pixels,ecc.

```
Could someone help me to figure out these type of limitations?
```

Comment: "*JSON must be readable from OpenGL ES libraries after conversion*" OpenGL ES is a rendering system. It is not capable of reading files, JSON or otherwise. Now, *your code* can read a file, but what you do with that file depends entirely on what you need to do with it.

Comment: I have to render with OpenGL "an" object which values are listed into a .JSON file I've created.Am I missing some steps?What are OpenGL inputs?I am totally new to this world and its 4 days I'm trying to figure out how this works.Anyway,thank you for your previous reply.

Comment: "*I am totally new to this world*" Then you're going about learning in completely the wrong way. OpenGL neither knows nor cares where the "values" come from. That's *your* job. What you need to know is how to rendering *something* in OpenGL. Once you understand that, *then* you can start looking into where the "something" comes from. But until you can render stuff with OpenGL, you won't be able to render stuff that comes from a file. Why do people always want to put the cart before the horse?